# Entity framework 6 custom keys for table-per-type inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, code-first

I need to transform some existing DB under a new application using EF6 with the CodeFirst approach. I am fighting with mapping conventions in inheritance. There is a minimal (not)working example:

Assume I have two tables: a Parent and a Child.

```
CREATE TABLE A_PARENT (
    A_PAR_ParentId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
    A_PAR_data VARCHAR(255)
)

CREATE TABLE B_CHILD (
   B_CHL_ChildId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES A_PARENT(A_PAR_ParentId),
   B_CHL_childData VARCHAR(255)
)
```

I successfuly solved the table prefices you can see, such the "A_PAR" using custom attributes. I believe the EF exactly knows what property belongs to which column and which one is the primary key. Everything works fine except for inheritance. Because when I attempt to get all of Children, I end up with a SQL error, because the EF produces a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    '0X0X' AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[A_PAR_ParentId] AS [A_PAR_ParentId], 
    [Extent1].[A_PAR_Data] AS [A_PAR_Data], 
    [Extent2].[B_CHL_ChildId] AS [B_CHL_ChildId], 
    [Extent2].[B_CHL_ChildData] AS [B_CHL_ChildData]
    FROM  [dbo].[A_PARENT] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[B_CHILD] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[A_PAR_ParentId] = [Extent2].[A_PAR_ParentId]
```

The only incorrect thing in the query is the join predicate - there is no such a column `A_PAR_ParentId` in the table `B_CHILD`.

How can I force the EntityFramework to use entity's primary key to use as a foreign key when constructing the inheritance chain? I am looking for some general solution based on conventions because all of the tables in the DB are using this pattern (if the type/table is inherited => the primary key is a foreign key to parent's primary key and there are no composite keys at all). Maybe I am looking for some way to tell the EF the PK is also a FK but without a navigation property.

--Edit: more code

The model is pretty simple:

```
    [ModulePrefix("A"), TablePrefix("PAR")]
    public class Parent
    {
        public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }

    [ModulePrefix("B"), TablePrefix("CHL")]
    public class Child : Parent
    {
        public Guid ChildId { get; set; }
        public string ChildData { get; set; }
    }
```

And the configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Types()
                .Where(type => !type.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<TableAttribute>().Any() && type.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<ModulePrefixAttribute>().Any())
                .Configure(config => config.ToTable(
                    ComposeDbName(GetModulePrefix(config.ClrType),
                    CamelCaseToUnderscore(GetClassName(config.ClrType)).ToUpper())
                    ));

            modelBuilder.Properties()
                .Where(property => property.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<TablePrefixAttribute>().Any() && property.DeclaringType == property.ReflectedType)
                .Configure(config => config.HasColumnName(ComposeDbName(
                    GetModulePrefix(config.ClrPropertyInfo.DeclaringType),
                    GetTablePrefix(config.ClrPropertyInfo.DeclaringType),
                    config.ClrPropertyInfo.Name
                    )));
            modelBuilder.Properties()
                .Where(property => property.Name == property.DeclaringType.Name + "Id" && property.ReflectedType == property.DeclaringType)
                .Configure(config => config.IsKey());

            modelBuilder.Properties()
                .Where(property => property.PropertyType.IsClass || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) != null)
                .Configure(config => config.IsOptional());
        }
```

There are some more private methods playing with columns/tables names. I think thats not important at this point since column/table names appear to be resolved well.

Comment: Let us see the Code First model/configuration related to the above db tables.

Comment: I've just added some code to the question.

Comment: `Child.ChildId` field is causing the issue.

Comment: Ivan: It appears you are definitely right. I've just seen some example saying something similar like you. So I have to place the identifier attribute to the base class only? What about the primary key of the descendant table and it's name? I dont want to have to name it `B_CHILD.B_CHL_ParentId` but `B_CHILD.B_CHL_ChildId`.

Answer (score 1):

> if the type/table is inherited => the primary key is a foreign key to parent's primary key

This is exactly how EF TPT inheritance mapping works, so no conflict here.

The problem is the `ChildId` property in `Child` class. Since `Child` inherits `Parent`, it also inherits `ParentId` property, ending up with incorrect TPT mapping. You have to remove it and use the base class defined property as PK (and FK), just give it a different name in the derived table.

I would suggest you using `Id` as name for the PK property to allow easily associating different name by convention.

So here is how the corrected model would look like:

```
[ModulePrefix("A"), TablePrefix("PAR")]
public class Parent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

[ModulePrefix("B"), TablePrefix("CHL")]
public class Child : Parent
{
    public string ChildData { get; set; }
}
```

and the configuration based on that convention:

```
modelBuilder.Types()
    .Where(type => !type.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<TableAttribute>().Any() && type.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<ModulePrefixAttribute>().Any())
    .Configure(config => config.ToTable(GetTableName(config.ClrType)));

modelBuilder.Properties()
    .Where(property => property.Name != "Id" && property.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<TablePrefixAttribute>().Any() && property.DeclaringType == property.ReflectedType)
    .Configure(config => config.HasColumnName(GetColumnName(config.ClrPropertyInfo.DeclaringType, config.ClrPropertyInfo.Name)));

modelBuilder.Properties()
    .Where(property => property.Name == "Id" && property.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<TablePrefixAttribute>().Any())
    .Configure(config => config.IsKey().HasColumnName(GetColumnName(config.ClrPropertyInfo.ReflectedType, "Id")));
```

which uses two new private helpers in addition to yours:

```
static string GetTableName(Type entityType)
{
    return ComposeDbName(
        GetModulePrefix(entityType),
        CamelCaseToUnderscore(GetClassName(entityType)).ToUpper()
    );
}

static string GetColumnName(Type entityType, string propertyName)
{
    return ComposeDbName(
        GetModulePrefix(entityType),
        GetTablePrefix(entityType),
        propertyName == "Id" ? GetClassName(entityType) + "Id" : propertyName
    );
}
```

What it does is to build conventionally the equivalent of this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().ToTable("A_PARENT");
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("A_PAR_ParentId");
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().Property(e => e.Data).HasColumnName("A_PAR_Data");

modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().ToTable("B_CHILD");
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("B_CHL_ChildId");
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().Property(e => e.ChildData).HasColumnName("B_CHL_ChildData");
```

Comment: Does not it assume the primary/foreign key name in the child table is named just equally as parent's primary key?

Comment: The suggested configuration generates the exact column names as in the database tables shown - `A_PAR_ParentId` and `B_CHL_ChildId`

Comment: The suggestion is to use uniform PK **property name** (in the classes) and map it to different column name in each table based on convention.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and sorry about my....... I tried to fix my code, then to copy-paste your code but I ended up with the same result (SQL query) like before. I am going to try it again from scratch in a new VS project.

Comment: You are welcome. No problem, this is exactly what I did (test in clean environment, latest EF6.1.3 if that matters) before posting it (only guessing the custom attributes and private methods).

Comment: Here is my complete test code: http://pastebin.com/LkHk1fx3
And I am getting the same result again and again.

Comment: The problem with your test is the `DbSet<Child> Children` in your `DbContext`. TPH (and other EF inheritance strategies) allow only `DbSet` of the base type. Remove that property and everything will be as expected.

Comment: Wow! You' re right. Can you please point me to the documentation about that limitation? Based on experience with other ORM frameworks this sounds to me pretty strange since there is absolutely no problem to generate query for a child type.
Practically: when I want to provide only instances of a sub-type, do I need to do something like this `context.Parent.Where(p => p is Child)` and hide it behind some facade/repository?

Comment: Documentation - you've got to be kidding :) All we have is some blog posts and examples. I personally find [Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 2 – Table per Type (TPT)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) series to be most useful. Basically all the EF inheritance strategies impose problems. And working with subclasses is limited to `is` operator and `OfType` method. I guess instead of `DbSet<Child>` you can expose `public IQueryable<Child> Children { get { return Parent.OfType<Child>(); } }`.